# Bind Data to Umbraco Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7, umbraco6

I want to bind Model Data to the form on Back Button
The Scenario is like On Continue I am saving the data into View Model and on Go Back I want to populate the Model data back to form

Answer (score 0):

there are various ways to do this. 
1) You can use jQuery to show/hide specific forms. A good example is available here http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/creating-a-simple-form-wizard-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

2)You can use TempData to save your viewmodels and retrive it back from TempData to bind it back to the form?

Does this help?